# Why is my real name showing in chat?

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

One of my questions ([How can I get the current activity while using Firebase Cloud Messaging in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63210429/1889720)) had its comments moved to chat.  In the chat, it shows my real name, not Evorlor.  It also will not let me continue the chat.  It tells me to log in, which takes me to my Evorlor account.  Then if I go back to chat, it says I am still not logged in.

What gives?

Comment: You can temporarily fix it by deleting your real name from the text box in the "Edit Profile and Settings" section.

Comment: It looks like you might've somehow triggered an account merge, and your chat profile isn't syncing properly... If that's correct, you could either wait an hour or so, or a mod might happen by and force sync the account.

Comment: This happens when you recreate a partially deleted account, using the same email ID. I have deleted the other chat account, you can join chat now.

Comment: Ouch, looks like deleting an account deletes the messages as well. I should have perhaps first taken a back up of the messages.

Comment: @BhargavRao All good.  That conversation was complete.  Thank you!!

Comment: That's perfect, let me delete the room. I've cleaned up the post as well.